# MassTransit StateMachine correlation by Int

Tags: masstransit

New to Masstransit here and I wanted to correlate my message with an int value (let's call it `OrderId` of type `INT`. I will use the same order management example from Masstransit).

I wanted to see if anyone was able to use an int to correlate events and messages in Masstransit.

I used this code in my events (both the events)

```
x.CorrelateById<int>(state => state.OrderId, context => context.Message.OrderId)
```

This compiles fine but then throws and exception

> NotImplementedByDesignException. Masstransit doc says : "Redis only supports event correlation by CorrelationId, it does not support queries. If a saga uses expression-based correlation, a NotImplementedByDesignException will be thrown."

I am using `CorrelateById()` so not sure why I am seeing this exception. I don't see any query here (or is it this func that returns the `OrderId`? The `correlationId` has a similar expression although it takes only one argument of  type:  `Func<ConsumeContext<TMessage>, Guid> selector`)

All I want is to be able to correlate message and event by an Int prop coming to my first event of the state machine. (That I have no control over by the way).

I feel creating another GUID just for Masstransit and link it to that `OrderId` is not the best option here.

My other question: is there any out of the box way in MassTransit to get the all event data for a specific `CorrelationId` (event sourcing style). I saw there was a `MassTransit.EventStoreIntegration` repo on github but since we can get the last version of the state instance I thought there would be a way to see all state instances/ or messages being persisted then pulled.

Sure I can see that in the log but I would like to see only the state changes that were pushed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation by anything other than the `Guid CorrelationId` property is a query. And, as you've found out, Redis doesn't support queries. If you need to correlate events using a type other than a `Guid`, Redis is not an option.

Comment: Thanks @chris. I thought so but I wanted to be sure. I must say I sofar love MT and been munching on your youtube vids. Great work. 
I might then just use Nosql with a little hit on performance.  
Do you have any suggestion for "event store" solution with MT if wanted to query more that the last version of the saga instance ?

Answer (score 1):

As per @Chris answer, and because I wanted to use an INT property and still use redis, I used Guid CorrelationId that was generated from that INT value with padded zeros.

```
CorrelationId = new Guid(OrderIdIntValue.ToString().PadLeft(32, '0'))
```

I am aware of the Guid vs int discussion in distributed systems.
For my case this works with no issues since that Int value is generated by a unique source of truth (that I consume and don't have control over).